# Flask server not accepting values from JS ajax function

Tags: javascript, python, flask

Python code -

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_cors import CORS
import cgi

app = Flask(__name__)
CORS(app)

form = cgi.FieldStorage()
var1 = form.getvalue('var1')

@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def apicall():
  if len(var1)>1:
    return 'received value from JS function'  

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app.run()
```

**error-: TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len().- "POST / HTTP/1.1" 500 -**

My javascript function -

```
function callPythonScript() {
                alert("called_python_script");
                $.ajax({
                    url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000",
                    type: "POST",
                    data:{ 
                        var1: window.location.href,
                    },
                    success: function(response) {
                        console.log(response);
                    },
                    error: function(xhr) {
                        console.log(xhr);
                    }
```

do i need configure my flask server to accept values from js func,
what i have tried is -

```
import cgi 
form = cgi.FieldStorage()
var1 = form.getvalue('var1')
```

PS: this setup works perfectly if i just pass return "Hello world" in python funx apicall()

Comment: You need to move ```var1 = form.getvalue('var1')``` inside the body of ```apicall()``` and you have to only use that code when you have a ```POST``` method

Comment: @NoCommandLine , i have tried that way previously,  moving var1 line inside my function call, it still doesnt work and returns ** TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
127.0.0.1 - - [31/Oct/2022 00:12:53] "POST / HTTP/1.1" 500 - **

Comment: 1). It should be inside that function. Its current location means it's always called immediately your file loads and the value will be None. 2) You're passing/trying to retrieve data the wrong way. See - https://stackoverflow.com/a/37631988/15211203

Comment: @NoCommandLine , followed both your suggestions and made modifications to my code accordingly , still no luck 
`@app.route("/", methods=['GET','POST'])
def apicall():
  var1 = None
  if request.method == "POST":
      var1 = form.getvalue('var1')
      if len(var1)>1:
        return 'received value from JS function'  `

Comment: @Fastnlight , could you please look at this bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you follow the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37631988/15211203), then your python code should be something like

```
@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def apicall():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        data = request.get_json() # Get all the data passed in (as JSON)
        var1 = data.get('var1', None)
        if var1 and len(var1)>1:
            return 'received value from JS function' 
        else:
            return 'No value from JS function'
    else:
       # Code to handle GET
```

Note that you're no longer using `form.get....` because you passed in JSON and not form data

Even if you submit a form, it's usually better to acccess the values as

`request.values.get(<var_name>, <default_value>)`

The above method allows you to specify a default value in the event <var_name> isn't available

Comment: Thanks for your help , apart from this i just had to add `contentType: 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',`
into my ajax function and it worked.